# Where can I purchase a funnel reflector?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, reflection, fiber-optics, optical-materials

I am designing a testing apparatus to contain the light emitted from a 40mm dia. xenon bulb and concentrate it at a 35mm dia. target.

My apparatus consists of a large funnel reflector: large hole dia. ≥ 60mm (added some clearance because, although the bulb is 40mm dia., it drops down 30mm from the top); small hole dia. = 35mm.

Another reflector, in the shape of a flat circle (w| 2 holes cut into it for the bulb's pos. and neg. leads to come through), will cap the funnel's large end (i.e., flat reflector dia. = large hole dia. of funnel).

The flat reflector was easy to find, I am having trouble finding a company who makes funnel shaped reflectors.

I found a patent which is essentially what I need (it is just miniature): https://patents.google.com/patent/US20030108295

The closest thing that I have been able to find are the ellipsoidal reflectors made by Edmund Optics:
https://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-mirrors/focusing-concave-mirrors/150mm-dia-x-360mm-fl-alum.-coated-ellipsoidal-reflector/

I have visited, called, and emailed every company that has turned up from my searching to no avail. Maybe one of you have resolved a search similar to mine and could recommend some companies? Or just as helpful, maybe there is better terminology or keywords I should be using to get better results?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason you want to avoid using more common devices designed to focus light, like parabolic reflectors and/or lenses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this post (v2) because shopping advices are off-topic.

Comment: @Tom B. The project is more focused on making sure that the target absorbs a certain amount of energy rather than a concentration of light. With that being said, although a lens would concentrate the light, a lot of energy would be lost in the form of heat if the light were to pass through the glass.

Comment: And @Qmechanic I believe that my question would fall under the topic of "Experimental technology used in physics or astronomy". If you disagree, please explain why?

Comment: @Qmechanic What do you suggest that I change?

Comment: The relevant meta post seems to be [this one](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/795). Now, I could be wrong (and I invite anyone having significant experience with this sort of hardware to correct me if so), but I don't think a funnel-shaped reflector counts as  "specialist equipment and materials".